# Sed gives error with unterminated substitute in Makefile

Tags: bash, sed, makefile

I'm trying to replace the last `,` in a command output

```
EXTRACT_JIRA_TICKETS=$(GIT_LOGS) | grep -e '[A-Z]\+-[0-9]\+' -o | sort -u |  tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$/\n/'

.Phony: check-jira-tickets
check-jira-tickets: ## checks if there are merged tickets without fix version
    @export JIRA_TICKETS_IDS=$(shell $(EXTRACT_JIRA_TICKETS)); \
    echo $${JIRA_TICKETS_IDS};
```

I've tried to escape the sed params with double quotes and nothing worked so far on Mac OS

```
$ make check-jira-tickets
sed: 1: "s/,\n/": unterminated substitute in regular expression
```

If I remove the pipe with sed it works

```
$ make check-jira-tickets
BEN-2783,
```

Comment: I haven't worked with `make` for long time, but if I remember correctly, `$/` is interpreted as expansion of a make-variable named `/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single dollar sign is special to `make` (here, it interprets `$/` as a make variable).

Double the dollar signs you want to propagate to the shell:

```
... | sed 's/,$$/\n/'
              ~~
```